# How to sort associated models by column in join model (:through)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models:

Event, Lineup, Artist

```
class Event
  has_many :lineups
  has_many :artists, -> { uniq }, through: :lineups
end

class Artist
  has_many :events, through: :lineups
  has_many :lineups
end

class Lineup
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

Lineup has `artist_order` integer column.

What can I do to have `Event.last.artists` sorted by lineup's `artist_order` column by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`default_scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope) for `Lineup` model:

```
class Lineup
  default_scope { order(:artist_order) } # or order('artist_order DESC')
end
```

This way whenever you call lineup collection, it is ordered by the `artist_order` column.

Other way is to specify the order directly on `has_many` relation:

```
has_many :lineups, -> { order(:artist_order) }
```

The latter might be the better option, because default_scope is sometimes [considered to be a bad idea](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2013/06/15/default_scope-is-evil/).

Comment: When I add default scope I get an error: `PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...ist_id" WHERE "lineups"."event_id" = $1  ORDER BY "lineups"....
                                                             ^
: SELECT DISTINCT "artists".* FROM "artists" INNER JOIN "lineups" ON "artists"."id" = "lineups"."artist_id" WHERE "lineups"."event_id" = $1  ORDER BY "lineups"."artist_order" ASC`

Comment: @MarcinDoliwa hm, let me think about it.. Are you sure you have association established correctly on the database layer? ( I mean, for example, does `lineups` column has event_id and artist_id

Comment: Yep it has both fields, and everything works fine withouth this `order`

Comment: When I remove { uniq } it stops throwing this error.

Comment: I removed uniq and my tests still passing, so I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just add `-> { order "artist_order ASC" }` to the `lineups` association in `Artist` model

```
Artist: 
  has_many :events, through: :lineups
  has_many :lineups, -> { order "artist_order ASC" }
```

Now `Event.last.artists` should give you the results sorted by lineup's `artist_order`

***PS:*** Not Tested.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Order in any association so just add `order` in front of `lineups` association.

```
has_many :lineups,-> { order(:artist_order) }
```

Check this http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many for complete reference.

Comment: what now does this answer brings?

Comment: I was writing answer before your answered this question. When I posted then saw your answer so updated my answer with the reference of Rails association from apidock